# Prove an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was looking at this proof that an open ball is not complete in $\mathbb{R}^n$. They showed that $\{u_k\}=\{(1-\frac{1}{n},0,0,0,...)\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ converging to $(1,0,0,...)$ by assuming without loss of generality, the open ball is the unit ball. Is this ok to do this or is there an easy way to generalize this to any ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$? They proved the sequence was cauchy by letting $\epsilon>0$ and choosing $N>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$ then for $k,l \geq N$ then $\sqrt{(1-\frac{1}{k}-(1-\frac{1}{l}))^2+(0-0)^2+\dots}=
|\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{l}|<\epsilon$. What would be a way to generalize this argument to any particular open ball?

Comment: This generalises pretty far. Every complete subset of a space is closed (regardless of whether the original space is complete or not!), so contrapositively, any non-closed subset of a space is incomplete.

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry I forgot to add the question specifically asks for a sequence

Comment: Replace the $1$ with $r$, and it works for a ball of any radius $r$ centered at the origin. Then, if it's centered elsewhere, shift individual coordinates as needed.

Comment: @ScottFrazier I didn't intend my comment to answer your question completely, but I thought it was an interesting remark given your final question.

Answer (score 2):

Given an open ball $B(a,r)$ centered at $a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with radius $r > 0$, it suffices to take $b\in\partial B(a,r)$.

Indeed, since $b$ is an adherent point of $B(a,r)$, there exists a sequence $x_{n}\in B(a,r)$ which converges to $b$.

But $B(a,r)$ is open, which means that $B(a,r)\cap\partial B(a,r) = \varnothing$. In particular, $b\not\in B(a,r)$.

Since $x_{n}$ is convergent, it is Cauchy. Then we have just proven there exists a Cauchy sequence in $B(a,r)$ that does not converge within it, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!